# Filter the GridView Data based on Checkbox which is outside of GridView?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have 5 check box on my page and a Grid view with Template Field, I am not using any bond field on page load I am binding the grid with all data of a table, I want to filter the data based on the check box check.

suppose: I have check box like A B C D. All check box are out side of Grid view. When user checked the check box A, then in Grid view, check box A related data should show, like wise for B C and D.

how do that?, Some one please give some example code and bit logic.

It would be great if I'll be able to filter the gridview without any postback.

Grid:

```
 <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" 
                AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellPadding="3">
      <Columns>
          <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ID" SortExpression="ID">
            <ItemTemplate>
              <asp:Label ID="lblId" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Id") %>'></asp:Label>
           </ItemTemplate>                           
         </asp:TemplateField>
         <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Discription" SortExpression="Discription">
            <ItemTemplate>
              <asp:Label ID="lblDiscription" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Discription") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>                        
         </asp:TemplateField>
         <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Address" SortExpression="Address">
            <ItemTemplate>
             <asp:Label ID="lblAddress" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Address") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
         </asp:TemplateField>
     </Columns>
 </asp:GridView>
```

Binding the Grid:

```
TestPageDao page1Dao = new TestPageDao ();

if (!IsPostBack)
{
  IList<TestDAO> TestDAO = page1Dao.GetAlldata();
  GridView1.DataSource = TestDAO;
  GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

I tried [Filter gridview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2739778/filter-gridview) or http://forums.asp.net/p/1034014/2904713.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to avoid postback, uses jQuery like here:
http://jquerybyexample.blogspot.com/2012/04/how-to-filter-gridview-records-using.html

An alternative is AJAX, but at the end of the story it is a postback-like approach.

Finally using postback you can do it in several ways by dynamically setting the GridView filter **before** the GridView loads. This can be achieved with the Page load event, the OnSelecting of the associated datasource (if any), or similar.

Here it is an extraction of the aspx:

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" Text="A" />
<asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox2" runat="server" Text="B" />
<asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox3" runat="server" Text="C" />
<asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox4" runat="server" Text="D" />
<hr />

<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" 
    DataSourceID="sqlDataSourceGridView" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
    CssClass="GridViewStyle" GridLines="None" Width="650px" >
    <Columns> 
        <asp:BoundField DataField="CompanyName" HeaderText="Company" ItemStyle-Width="200px" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ContactName" HeaderText="Name" ItemStyle-Width="125px"/>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="City" HeaderText="city" ItemStyle-Width="125px" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Country" HeaderText="Country" ItemStyle-Width="125px" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>

<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSourceGridView" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:northWindConnectionString %>" 
    SelectCommand="SELECT [CustomerID], [CompanyName], [ContactName], [City], [Country] FROM [Customers]" 
    OnSelecting="SqlDataSourceGridView_Selecting">
 <FilterParameters>
    <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="checkbox1" Name="CompanyName" PropertyName="Checked" ConvertEmptyStringToNull="false" />
 </FilterParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Note the OnSelecting event and note that there isn't any filter preset.

Now in the code behind set dynamically the filter:

```
protected void SqlDataSourceGridView_Selecting(object sender, SqlDataSourceSelectingEventArgs e) {
    SqlDataSourceGridView.FilterExpression = string.Empty;
    if (CheckBox1.Checked) {
        SqlDataSourceGridView.FilterExpression += "(CompanyName=1)";
    }
    if (CheckBox2.Checked) {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(SqlDataSourceGridView.FilterExpression)) SqlDataSourceGridView.FilterExpression += " OR ";
        SqlDataSourceGridView.FilterExpression += "(B=1)";
    }
    if (CheckBox3.Checked) {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(SqlDataSourceGridView.FilterExpression)) SqlDataSourceGridView.FilterExpression += " OR ";
        SqlDataSourceGridView.FilterExpression += "(C=1)";
    }
    if (CheckBox4.Checked) {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(SqlDataSourceGridView.FilterExpression)) SqlDataSourceGridView.FilterExpression += " OR ";
        SqlDataSourceGridView.FilterExpression += "(D=1)";
    }
}
```

If you don't like the OnSelecting event, you can do the same in the PageLoad:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    // here same code of above
    // . . .
}
```

I didn't test it so verify minor errors.

Comment: Can I do that without using Datasource, Actually I am getting the record from my DAO and binding the grid on page load, plz see my updated ans.

Comment: Will you please tell me in A=1, B=1 what is 1. i did the same but filtering is not working

Comment: and check i am making the check box check then also its not firing

Comment: Using the postback without DataSource is even simpler: for example filter your data in the Page_Load by reading the checkbox status, then bind the GridView. If you want to automatically post, set the checkbox option to automatically post on click.

Comment: Change them in the real fields you want to filter on