# How to apply a filter expression to a gridview?

Tags: c#, asp.net, devexpress

I have this grid view and a filter expression that I get from database.
Now I want to apply the filter expression to the grid so the data from the grid be sort.
The column from the criteria match with the column of the grid. This isn't the problem.

I can set `grid.FilterExpression = filter` , but how can I sort the values to grid like the filter criteria?

Comment: Is your component a `GridView` from `System.Web.UI.WebControls` ?
If you want to sort, you need to use `GridView.Sort()` with your expression.

Comment: It's a DevExpress AspxGridView

Comment: Did you check this documentation article: [ASPxGridView sorting](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/CustomDocument3714).

Answer (score 1):

Code:
HTML Markup to Populate Dropdowns
    
     All

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="sqlDataSourceCity" runat="server" 
ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:northWindConnectionString %>" 
SelectCommand="SELECT DISTINCT City FROM Customers">
</asp:SqlDataSource>


<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlCountry" runat="server" 
                  AppendDataBoundItems="True" 
                  AutoPostBack="True" 
                  DataSourceID="sqlDataSourceCountry" 
                  DataTextField="Country" 
                  DataValueField="Country" Width="100px">
<asp:ListItem Value="%">All</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>


<asp:SqlDataSource ID="sqlDataSourceCountry" runat="server" 
ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:northWindConnectionString %>" 
SelectCommand="SELECT DISTINCT [Country] FROM [Customers]">
```

HTML markup of gridview and sqldatasource with filter expression

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" 
              AllowPaging="True" 
              DataSourceID="sqlDataSourceGridView" 
              AutoGenerateColumns="False"
              CssClass="GridViewStyle" 
              GridLines="None" Width="650px" 
              ShowHeader="false">
<Columns>
<asp:BoundField DataField="CustomerID" HeaderText="Customer ID"/>
<asp:BoundField DataField="CompanyName" HeaderText="Company"/>
<asp:BoundField DataField="ContactName" HeaderText="Name"/>
<asp:BoundField DataField="City" HeaderText="city"/>
<asp:BoundField DataField="Country" HeaderText="Country"/>
</Columns>
</asp:GridView>


<asp:SqlDataSource ID="sqlDataSourceGridView" 
                   runat="server" 
ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:northWindConnectionString %>" 
SelectCommand="SELECT [CustomerID], [CompanyName], [ContactName], 
[City], [Country] FROM [Customers]" 
FilterExpression="[City] like '{0}%' and [Country] like '{1}%'">
<FilterParameters>
<asp:ControlParameter ControlID="ddlCity" Name="City" 
                      PropertyName="SelectedValue" 
                      Type="String" />
<asp:ControlParameter ControlID="ddlCountry" Name="Country" 
                      PropertyName="SelectedValue" 
                      Type="String" />
</FilterParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Source :-http://csharpdotnetfreak.blogspot.com/2011/04/gridview-filterexpression-dropdownlist.html

Comment: I don't select in this page the filterexpression. I already have the filter expression and I want to apply it to the grid view

Comment: can check out this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10246255/filter-the-gridview-data-based-on-checkbox-which-is-outside-of-gridview OR this piece of code http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/scottlysle/using-filter-expressions-with-an-sql-data-source-in-Asp-Net-C-Sharp/

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to read this useful article

http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxGridViewASPxGridView_FilterExpressiontopic